# Music glitch appears out of nowhere

Tags: animation, audio

I prepared my test animation beforehand. Everything was going well until I started adding cameras. Then when camera switches music becomes louder / lower and then randmomly speeds up.

Happens not only in preview but also in render. How do I fix this? It took me 20 hours to make and for it to be ruined at the last step is really discouraging.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEReUdjCmnk

I recorded the glitch. I will appreciate any help

Comment: Sometimes it helps to append whole scene into fresh .blend file.

Comment: Tried that, it's better but never perfect. Guess ill have to add music externally.

Comment: Did you try different codec, AAC or AC3?

Comment: Yup, MAYBE it's slightly better, but in the end there is visible click or volume change when cameras switch

Comment: What if put sound in separate scene (Scene_2) and render actual animation as `Scene` strip from VSE of Scene_2